Python decode() mangles bytes object (either returns empty string, or only last line of text)
For the life of me, I can't figure out what's happening here...
I'm capturing the output of a command line utility via subprocess.popen(), and processing the stdout line by line via process.stdout.readline() (which returns a bytes object). I want to convert each stdout line to a string, but when I convert it with output.decode(), it either (1) returns an empty string (even though there is text in the bytes object), or (2) only returns the last line in the bytes object.
I have looked through the python docs for Code.decode, but can't figure out why this is happening or how to remedy it.
Below is a snippet of the code I'm using, and some example outputs.
Code snippet:
output = process.stdout.readline()  # returns a bytes object
if output:
    print(str(output))
    print(output.decode())

Example 1 (only last line being returned by decode()):
first print statement (the bytes object):
b'0M Scan  C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\\r                                                                              \r24 folders, 8 files, 65 bytes (1 KiB)'

second print statement (result of decode()):
24 folders, 8 files, 65 bytes (1 KiB)
(I would expect it to be this:)
Scan  C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\
24 folders, 8 files, 65 bytes (1 KiB)

Example 2 (decode() returning empty string):
first print statement (the bytes object):
b'0%'
second print statement (result of decode()):
"" (an empty string)
(I would expect it to be this:)
0%
I have tried output.decode('utf-8') but the same result. output is NOT being accessed/modified elsewhere. Why might this be happening? Could this be because I'm on a Windows machine?

For some reason the program is returning \r as the line feeds.
Please enable text=True on the popen, or add the correct encoding, in order to automatically enable universal newlines.
Otherwise, replace all \r with \n manually or wrap the stdout with io.TextIOWrapper and newline=\r.

Considering all the spaces, I think it's deliberately trying to overprint the previous output.

You need to decide if it's deliberate, but the problem you're facing is clearly the carriage return overwriting the data. In the case of percentage, it makes sense as it's probably a progress bar. If you wish to not override, my answer will work. If you do wish to override, then you have answered your question :-)

Oh wow! adding text=True to popen worked perfectly for me, as now process.stdout.readline() is returning Strings rather than a bytes object (so I do not even need to deal with decode()). Thank you so much! However, I'm quite curious: why are the \r an issue with decode()? What do you mean they are overwriting the data? Why does this happen? And yes, it's a progress bar, and I do want to capture it, because I want to show the progress to the user. (By the way, I think the program is returning \r\n because I'm on Windows; I'm assuming on linux it would just be \n.)

@bikz So it is returning \r because it attempts to overwrite the progress bar, not because you're on Windows. You need to remember that printing \r results in the current line being deleted up until that point. .decode() simply ignores the "uniqueness" of \r, while text=True converts the \r to \n using the universal newlines algorithm (basically any \r, \n or \r\n are converted to \n).

Oh. I was unaware of this. Thank you so much for explaining. I hope this helps someone in the future as well. I've been wrecking my brain over this for a couple days. This makes sense, because if you execute this program on the cmd line, the percentages (progress) keep updating. I was curious how they did that, now it makes sense.
